# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId =

Tags: magento, magento2

I am getting this issue:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = *

I am getting this issue on my cart page only when cart page is blank. Otherwise, it works fine.

And I am using only one default store.

[image]

Comment: I tried all github methods but none them is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check table "customer_entity" and check columns: 'failures_num',first_failure,lock_expires'. If they aren't available than create them:

```
'failures_num', smallint(6) default 0
first_failure timestamp default NULL
lock_expires. imestamp default NULL
```